# Capactior 4 doesn't show notifications dialog to accept or not on Android

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, capacitor

UPDATED CODE

Hello i am using push notifications and fcm to send notifications for my project. It works just fine on iOS but it doesn't on Android version of capacitor.

I am getting the Notification if i am sending Firebase console Messaging.

Plus the token of the device -value on PushNotifications.addListener('registration', async ({ value }) => {
console.log(value);- keeps changing everytime i install the project.

home.ts

```
      async ngOnInit() {
        this.userData.registerFCM();
    }
```

userData service

```
async registerFCM() {

PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then(async result => {
    if (result.receive === 'granted') {
        if (Capacitor.getPlatform() === 'android') {
            await PushNotifications.register()
            PushNotifications.addListener('registration', async ({ value }) => {
                console.log(value);

                this.submitFCM(value);
            });
          }
          else{
        // Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
        await PushNotifications.register();

        // Get FCM token instead the APN one returned by Capacitor
        FCM.getToken()
            .then((r) => {
                console.log(`Token: ${r.token}`)

                this.submitFCM(r.token);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        }
    } else {
        // Show some error
    }
});

 let device: any = await Device.getInfo();
   let id = await Device.getId();
    device.uuid = id.uuid;

     this.device = device;
  }
```

function submitFCM()

```
  async submitFCM(token) {
    console.log('token', token);

    let url = this.appData.getApiUrl() + 'registerFCM'; 
    let data = this.jsonToURLEncoded({
        api_signature: this.api_signature,
        registrationId: token,
        app_version: this.appData.APP_VERSION,

        device: {
            platform: this.device.platform,
            uuid: this.device.uuid,
            model: this.device.model,
            manufacturer: this.device.manufacturer,
            version: this.device.version,
        }
    });

    this.http.post(url, data, { headers: this.options })
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('Push has been registered', data);
    })
}
```

The data is being stored on db just fine. The token also stores BUT ITS DIFFERENT EVERYTIME.

Plus I am not getting the MESSAGE DIALOG as i supposed to let my project to Allow Notifications or not, but i get them on iOS version

any help?

Comment: At first glance the code looks all legit...  I recommend double checking you've followed all the instructions for Android setup on https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-community/fcm and https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications

Comment: Could it be a SHA1 certificate thing or google.services.json?

Comment: I dont think its a plugin error because i should get the notification from POSTMAN right? plus i am worried that i am not getting the pop up message to allow notifications or not but i do on iOS version